# How handle binding ObservableCollections when implementing MVVM Pattern in a blazor application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm, blazor, observablecollection

Since the page classes in my blazor application are getting somewhat long and untidy and I'm coming originally from WPF development anyway, I thought, I have a look into MVVM-ifying my application.

**Preliminaries:**

Here is my ViewModelBase

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return;
        storage = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

And here is a relevant of the relevant ViewModel and the corresponding interface for the Dependency-Injection system:

```
public class DatasetManagerViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDatasetManagerViewModel
{
    private DatasetModel _selectedDataset;
    public DatasetModel SelectedDataset 
    { 
        get { return _selectedDataset;}
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedDataset, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ImageModel> DatasetFiles { get; set; } = new();
}

public interface IDatasetManagerViewModel
{
    event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    ObservableCollection<ImageModel> DatasetFiles { get; set; }
    DatasetModel SelectedDataset { get; set; }
}
```

In the View/Page Class this is implemented as follows:

```
[Inject]
protected IDatasetManagerViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

private async void OnPropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    await InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    });
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    ViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChangedHandler;   
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
// also unsubscribe event after disposal
```

**Question:**

This works fine in case of normal properties such as in case of the above `SelectedDataset`.
However, I'm wondering what the best way is to bind an `ObservableCollection` such as `DatasetFiles` to the view class to incorporate the `CollectionChanged` event (If I recall correctly this is done automatically in WPF when a GUI element is bound to an `ObservableCollection`?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meanwhile I changed my `ViewModelBase` to the following:

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value,
        [CallerMemberName] string property = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return;
        storage = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    protected void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
    }
}
```

Any ViewModel with an `ObservableCollection` is then responsible to subscribe the added `OnCollectionChanged()` to the `CollectionChanged` event.
If anyone comes up with a nicer solution, I'd be interessted :)